# Set a grid row to automatic but dont expand past remaining available space

Tags: wpf

Because a child control is a scrollviewer, I cannot use a stack panel due to its tendency to grow beyond parent containers constraints.

I have a grid with several rows, one of the center rows needs to collapse when doesn't contain much but still expand to `*` (the remaining available space) when full, the row has a scroll viewer inside that will handle overflow past that point.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type IMPI:SettingGroup}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Description}"/>

        <!-- I want this row to shrink when its size is less than the remaining space determined by "*" -->
        <TabControl Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" Visibility="{Binding Groups, Converter={StaticResource VisibleIfItemsPresent}}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>

        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Settings}" Visibility="{Binding Settings, Converter={StaticResource VisibleIfItemsPresent}}"/>

    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Just add `VerticalAlignment="top"` to your TabControl. It will "collapse" vertically based on the ContentPresenter's content, and grow to the limit set by the "*" row height. Once this is reached the scrollviewer should kick in with its vertical scroll bar.

Comment: Is there any way for you to calculate the MaxHeight for Row 2?  You want an Auto height with a max height.

`<Setter Property="RowDefinition.MaxHeight" Value="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestoryType=Grid}, Converter={StaticResource SomeMathConverter??}, ConverterParameter='SomeConstantPixels?'}"`